# sql server complex join query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

I have the following query, it is working but I get 4 columns (3 named the same way) because what I want is just get two columns with the data, "Entidad" and "Servicio" but can't find the way to do it..

```
SELECT
    Entidades.nombre as entidad,
    Servicios.nombre as servicio,
    sp.nombre        as servicio,
    sc.nombre        as servicio
FROM
    Entidades

LEFT JOIN Banksphere 

    INNER JOIN Servicios
    ON Banksphere.servicio_id = Servicios.id

ON Entidades.id = Banksphere.entidad_id

LEFT JOIN PAS 

     INNER JOIN Servicios sp
     ON sp.id = 3

ON Entidades.id = PAS.entidad_id

LEFT JOIN CAM 

    INNER JOIN Servicios sc
    ON sc.id = 0

ON Entidades.id = CAM.entidad_id
GROUP BY
    Entidades.id, Entidades.nombre, Servicios.nombre, sp.nombre, sc.nombre
ORDER BY
    Entidades.id
```

The structure I got is this

```
Entidad     | Servicio | Servicio | Servicio
Corporativo | Abacon   | NULL     | CAM
Corporativo | MCI      | NULL     | CAM
Santander   | Sales    | PAS      | NULL
```

But I want this...

```
Entidad     | Servicio
Corporativo | Abacon 
Corporativo | MCI    
Corporativo | CAM
Santander   | Sales   
Santander   | PAS
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the `UNPIVOT` function:

```
select DISTINCT entidad, value   -- use distinct if you want to remove duplicates
from
(
    SELECT
        Entidades.nombre as entidad,
        Servicios.nombre as servicio1,
        sp.nombre as servicio2,
        sc.nombre as servicio3
    FROM
        Entidades
    LEFT JOIN
        (Banksphere INNER JOIN Servicios
    ON (Banksphere.servicio_id = Servicios.id))
    ON Entidades.id = Banksphere.entidad_id
    LEFT JOIN
        (PAS INNER JOIN Servicios sp
    ON (sp.id = 3))
    ON Entidades.id = PAS.entidad_id
    LEFT JOIN
        (CAM INNER JOIN Servicios sc
    ON (sc.id = 0))
    ON Entidades.id = CAM.entidad_id
    GROUP BY
        Entidades.id, Entidades.nombre, Servicios.nombre, sp.nombre, sc.nombre
) src
unpivot
(
    value
    for col in (servicio1, servicio2, servicio3)
) unpiv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/69feb/2)

Comment: That is working but I get duplicated records for "Servicios" if "Entidades" has it... For example

Santander | PAS
Santander | Movilidad
Santander | Superlinea
Santander | PAS

I need to get just one "Servicio" for each "Entidad" if it has it

Comment: You can use the `DISTINCT` keyword on the outer select to remove duplicates. See my edit.

Comment: One more thing... I need to SUM the column "Reconocido" from the "Banksphere, PAS and CAM" tables... and show it like this...

Santander | PAS | X (Where X is the SUM for that "Servicio") Can you help me?

Comment: @user1381537 my suggestion would be to post a new question as what you included does not have anything that can be summed that way.